# draw circle and then move it around using html canvas and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry, drag

I would like to know how to draw a circle using html5's canvas and move it around. I already have the code for drawing a circle, but after that is finished, I want to drag it around. I was trying to figure the implementation of the codes following the sequence of actions (draw --> move), but not sure how to build it using canvas and JS. Anybody can help me??

Below is my code:

HTML

```
<body>
  <h1>Circle</h1>
  <div class="circle">
    <canvas id="myCanvasCircle" width="500" height="500"> your browser does not support HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

  </div>

</body>
```

JS

```
<script>

  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvasCircle'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      circle = {},
      drag = false;

  function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.X, circle.Y, circle.radius, 0, 2.0 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

  }

  function mouseDown(e) {

    circle.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    circle.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    circle.X = circle.startX;
    circle.Y = circle.startY;

    circle.radius = 0;

    drag = true;
  }

  function mouseUp() {
    drag = false;

  }

  function mouseMove(e) {
    if (drag) {
      circle.X = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      circle.Y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
      circle.radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((circle.X - circle.startX), 2) + Math.pow((circle.Y - circle.startY), 2));
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      draw();


    }
  }

  function init() {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);

  }

  init();

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to draw just one circle, it's fairly simple to modify your code to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/15dkrakj/2/

```
circleMade = false;

//In mouseDown
if (!circleMade) {
    circle.radius = 0;
}

function mouseUp() {
    drag = false;
    circleMade = true;
}

//In mouseMove
if (!circleMade) {
    circle.radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((circle.X - circle.startX), 2) + Math.pow((circle.Y - circle.startY), 2));
}
```

Just don't change the radius after the first mouse down and up.

If you're wanting to be able to draw multiple circles, and drag each one... that's a bit more complicated.

**To answer question in comments:**

http://jsfiddle.net/15dkrakj/3/

```
mouseMoved = false

//In mouse up
if(!mouseMoved){
    circle = {};
    circleMade = false;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}    
mouseMoved = false;

function mouseMove(e) {
    if (drag) {
        mouseMoved = true;
        ...
```

This tracks whether the mouse was pressed down and moved. If the mouse isn't moved while it's pressed down, on mouse up clear the screen and empty the circle.

Comment: thanks Devin! Now I get the concept of implementing it. In the meantime, I have one more thing to ask. So after the circle is drawn and moved around, I want to erase it by clicking the circle. any suggestion on doing that??

Comment: Meaning a left click without movement, or right click menu?

Comment: left click... sorry for misguide

Comment: one more thing by the way, and I won't ask you to give me your code to do this additional feature. is there any good reference i can take a look at in order to implement the control points? i would like to add an additional feature in which if you lick the boundary of the circle shape, the shape changes as the mouse goes. is it that the implementation is done on top of this already existent circle, or should I use a different function to create a circle with the control points?

Comment: You could check out fabric.js to see how they've implemented it? http://fabricjs.com/ Honestly, if you need to create a complex canvas editing feature, I recommend using a library. Unless, of course, you're doing this for fun.